# Linear combination of Bernstein polynomials: necessary and sufficient conditions for positivity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $k$ be an integer larger than or equal to $1$, let $a_0,...,a_k$ be $k$ real-valued constants and define:

$$p_n(w)=\sum_{j=0}^k a_j  \binom{k}{j}w^j (1-w)^{k-j}, \quad w \in [0,1]$$

Is it true that $p_n(w)\geq0$, $\forall w \in [0,1]$ if and only if $a_j \geq 0$, $\forall j \in \{0,...,k \}$? The result is true (trivial) when $k=1$. Also, it is obvious that in order $p_n$ to be non-negative on $[0,1]$, it must be that $a_0\geq 0$ and $a_k \geq 0$. But what about the other coefficients $a_j$, $j=1,...,k-1$? Clearly, if they are all non-negative $p_n$ is non-negative, but what about the converse statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k=2$ we already get a counterexample: $$p_k(w) = \binom20 w^2 - \frac12 \binom21 w(1-w) + \binom22 (1-w)^2 = 3\left(w - \frac12\right)^2 + \frac14$$ is always positive, even though $a_1 = -\frac12$.

One thing we *can* say is that the inequality $$\binom kj \left(\frac jk\right)^j\left(1 - \frac jk\right)^{k-j} > \binom ki \left(\frac jk\right)^i\left(1 - \frac jk\right)^{k-i}$$ holds for any $i$: this is saying that the $\operatorname{Binomial}(k, \frac jk)$ distribution has its only mode at $j$. So if $a_j$ is negative and $$|a_j| \ge \sum_{i \ne j} \max\{a_i, 0\},$$ then at $\frac jk$, the $j^{\text{th}}$ term will dominate, and $p_k(\frac jk) < 0$.